# Changing Cloud function regions while using NodeJS

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I know that this question has been asked quite a lot, and the common answer is adding a region like this:

```
export.webhookEurope = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
});
```

But in my case, I'm working with the *onCreate* method, and sampling the above code in my function just throws me an error. Code looks like this.

```
export const onCreate = functions.firestore
.document('parent/{id}')
.region('europe-west1')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    // some code which deploys correctly if I leave out the 'region'    
});
```

So deploying without the 'region' part works fine, but if I leave it in, it gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

So what would be the correct way of changing the default region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the call to `region()` in the wrong part of the builder.  It comes before the identification of the product you're triggering on:

```
export const onCreate = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.firestore
.document('parent/{id}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    // some code which deploys correctly if I leave out the 'region'    
});
```

The [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions) might be helpful in the future.  Especially [FunctionBuilder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_builder_.functionbuilder).

Comment: You saved me again Doug, thank you so much. Btw your YT Firebase tutorial is amazing :)